# Displaying NumberLinePlot Vertically?

Tags: plotting

Is it possible to have `NumberLinePlot[]` display that axis vertically instead of horizontally?

Comment: `Rotate[NumberLinePlot[Prime[Range[10]]], 90 Degree]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was thinking along the same lines as Hubble07, but I don't care for the way the tick labels get rotated.

```
Rotate[NumberLinePlot[x^3 < Sin[13 x], x], π/2]
```

[image]

So you can use this,

```
verticalNumberLinePlot[pred__] := Rotate[
  NumberLinePlot[
   pred,
   Ticks -> {Function[{min, max},
      N@Join[{#, Rotate[#, -π/2], {.01, 0}} & /@ 
         FindDivisions[{min, max}, 5],
        {#, "", {.005, 0}} & /@ FindDivisions[{min, max}, 25]]]}],
  π/2]
```

It *seems* to work just as `NumberLinePlot`, with any option or input specification.  I tried on several of the examples on the reference page and none of them broke the functionality.

```
{verticalNumberLinePlot[x^3 < Sin[13 x], x],
 verticalNumberLinePlot[Prime[Range[10]]],
 verticalNumberLinePlot[{{Interval[{0, 1}]}, Interval[{0, 2}]}]}
```

[image]

**Edit** I had originally used `AbsoluteOptions` to get the tick marks, but I found it to be obscenely slow, doesn't work with all versions of *Mathematica*, and didn't give the best results.  So I switched to using a custom tick function as above.  I wish the function could be smaller, but I'm happy with the results.